# catch exception in mfc callback function

Tags: mfc

I'm using vc2008, writing some MFC code, I add a button, double click it, and vc2008 automatically create a callback function for me, and my code is like this:

```
void CDeviceTesterDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    try {
        ....
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        ....
    };
}
```

the problem is, I need place this ugly code in every OnBnClickedButtonXXX function,
are there any good method only place the code in one place?

A example in PyQt, I use this method:

```
def excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    QMessageBox.warning(None, "", "%s: %s" % (str(type), str(value)))
    return sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)
sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This is not equivalent to try/catch but it's similar to your PyQt example.